# Is it possible to have golden beef meat with normal spices?

Tags: beef

I wonder how a restaurant able to cook beef until golden colour with normal spices and cooking such in following picture?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

What you are seeing here is the early stages of a '[Malliard Reaction](https://www.thespruceeats.com/what-is-the-maillard-reaction-995776?utm_source=pinterest&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=mobilesharebutton2)' where beef is typically "browned". However, in the picture you provide the cook has managed to land on "golden brown" (stopping before the more common deep brown coloration). Another 30 seconds on the heat and this meat would be that darker brown that is more commonly associated with beef.

An additional factor is the hue of the photo, purely for artistic effect, the meat is placed next to yellow onions, white rice (?), on a white & blue plate. This creates a perception that it is more yellowish.

[image]

In this image I have taken a segment from your picture and dropped it on top  of a segment of a steak photo. Here, it looks (at least IMHO) more brownish and definitely fits the color pallet of the steak.

[image]

In short, it is partially how it's cooked and partially how it is staged. The Spices don't really play into it unless you are using too much spice to begin with.